# T-SQL stored procedure timing out on assigning query results to a parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that has been running well for a few weeks.  It does a lot and typically takes 10 seconds to run.

There have been no changes, but now it times out.

I've simulated the code where it chokes below. It creates a parameter, assigns it, and prints it.  It takes over a minute sometimes:

```
declare @myDec decimal(10,2);
set @myDec = (select sum(Hours) 
              from VATT_Time_Entries_With_Costs_For_Invoicing 
              where date >= getDate() - 110 and date <= getDate() - 18.75)  -- /3
```

The exact same query, just not assigning it to a parameter, runs in under a second:

```
select sum(Hours) 
from VATT_Time_Entries_With_Costs_For_Invoicing 
where date >= getDate() - 110 and date <= getDate() - 18.75
```

I'm perplexed as I've written hundreds of lines of code that work like this without issues.

Comment: What does `getDate()-110` do? Whatever it does is non-standard behaviour - I would highly recommend using the correct datetime functions. Is `VATT_Time_Entries_With_Costs_For_Invoicing ` a view by chance?

Comment: Manually force an update on the statistics on the underlying table, and/or the index on the date column if you have such an index.

Comment: Do both queries produce the same execution plan ?

Comment: Please share both query plans using https://pastetheplan.com. Please also show the table and indexes. Without this info we cannot answer this question.

Comment: Aside: Consider using a [covering index](http://www.dbadiaries.com/sql-server-covering-index-and-key-lookup/), i.e. indexed on `date` and _including_ `Hours`, to improve performance.

Comment: Thanks Dale K, these find a date 110 days and 18.75 days before right now.   Removing these from the query and putting them as parameters, and setting them above running the query made a major improvement (from one minute to less than a second).   I'm still not clear why running the query on its own vs. assigning to a parameter made such a difference.

Comment: Without seeing the plans we can't say for sure, but here's a common scenario with dates: Dates in a database tend to have higher values over time, for obvious reasons. SQL keeps track of a histogram of values in a table, but this is only updated occasionally. So, suppose you add thousands of rows to a large table, with a new high date value. There's no such date in the statistics, so SQL estimates no rows will be found, and builds a plan using that (which will actually estimate one row). But it should have used a plan which estimated lots of rows. It was misled by out of date statistics....

Comment: ... So why is it better with a variable? Because with a local variable SQL will act as though it doesn't know the variables value. It will "optimize for unknown", meaning it will (except in specific circumstances) just guess that some fraction of the rows in the table will be returned. And so it builds a plan that works well for several thousand rows. And as it happens, there *were* several thousand rows with these new large dates. So the less specific plan actually works better.

Comment: And finally, why were your first two queries so different, before you created the parameter query? Because SQL caches plans, and reuses them. Per GuidoG's question, at least one of your original queries probably had a cached plan that was being reused, which was different from the plan used for the other query.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the date functions *getDate()-110*  from the query and putting them as parameters, and setting them above running the query made a major improvement (from one minute to less than a second). I'm still not clear why running the query on its own vs. assigning to a parameter made such a difference. Thanks to all commentators.

Comment: Probably because the resulting statistics histogram was different, causing a different estimated number of rows (even though the result is the same). Without an execution plan we cannot diagnose this.

Comment: _putting them as parameters_ Parameters? Or local variables? Those are very different things.